# NSString crashes while logging to file

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, nsstring

I have a Bluetooth device that sends accelerometer data at 400hz per second. I use this data to do several things: 1.) animate a wheel based on this data and 2.) standard deviations.

My problem is, however, that after some time (*after 1000's of lines printed*), the app crashes at the same line where I create an NSString with the data so I can write that data to a text file. When this crash happens, I check each variable in the string to make sure it is valid and each are. I have seen the NSString report itself to be an (INT), so I assumed there was a memory leak somewhere.

I have added an `@autoreleasepool{}`, but the same line crashes. Here is a screenshot of that.

[image]
How can I find out what is causing the crash?

Comment: Is the application multithreaded?

Comment: Yes it is multithreaded.

Comment: Is this method thread-safe? Are there any locks? Looks like tread safety problem to me

Comment: No locks. I receive the data from CoreBluetooth callback and send the bytes through a delegate method. There is a for loop that creates an array of the x,y,x values.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by adding `copy` to `_locationString`.

```
[_locationString copy]
```

Comment: So do you know why it happened then as that fix doesn't seem too solid to me.  Better would be to use a property for `locationString` that has the `copy` attribute so it's copied when set, not when used (plus you won't need that code every time you access it).

Comment: I did set the property for the `locationString` to `copy`. For some reason, I had to also add the above. Not sure why.

Comment: If it's a property then you should be using the getter (i.e. `self.locationString`).